# How to deal with a connection made to a local datasouce file for a Published PowerBI report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have a published report with a file lying locally on my computer.
With Path shown by the PowerBI service as "C:\Users\Data\Data.csv"

Now, my Published report is not able to be access and refresh (It shows Offline when I click on refresh ) it as it's lying offline. Is there a way I upload this CSV file somewhere and change the Data Source Path?

How should I tackle this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. You can install a [gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) on your local machine to make the path visible to the PBI Service.

Alternatively, upload the CSV to a web location and use the web connector or something like Sharepoint and retrieve the file from there.